# Play sound with end of timer

Tags: javascript

I have a countdown script where JavaScript changes the background color to yellow as timer reaches 20 seconds left and then red when timer reaches 0. I would also like to play a sound once when the timer reaches 0. Background color change works correctly but sound does not play:

```
function changeColor(timer) {
if (timer > 20) {
document.body.style.background = "green";
}

else if (timer <= 20 && timer > 0) {
document.body.style.background = "yellow";
}

else {
document.body.style.background = "red";
document.getElementById("audio").play();
}
}
```

At the top of the page under  I have added:

```
<audio id="audio" src="magic.mp3" autoplay="false" ></audio>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What's the lifecycle of `timer`? Create a minimal snippet

Comment: Keep in mind that chrome added a safety feature wich does not allow sound to be played until the user interacts with the site (i.e. click on a button).

Comment: Did not know of Chrome safety feature. Wow!

Comment: Adam the timer is just 1 minute at start and then changes Page background with 20 seconds left and at 0 time left.